# Setting the session timeout to only refresh page if user is inactive and reset it if user is active?

Tags: java, jsp, session, authentication, session-timeout

My session timeout is refreshing the webpage back to the login page even if the user is active, no matter what.  How do I set it so that it ONLY refresh the webpage back to the login page IF the user is **inactive**?

```
int timeout = 10;  //Right now I'm experimenting with a 10 second value 
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Views/Home.jsp");

response.setHeader("Refresh", timeout + "; URL=Login.jsp");

session.setAttribute("msgErrorTimeout", "Your session has timed out.");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Why does the line of code below automatically refreshes the page even if the user is ACTIVE on the page?  I only want it to automatically refresh if the user has been INACTIVE for 10 seconds:

```
response.setHeader("Refresh", timeout + "; URL=UserLogin.jsp");
```

Or in other words, is there somehow I can reset the session timeout counter back to 10 seconds if the user is active on the page (ie. the cursor moves within the page, any key is pressed, or a button/link is clicked, etc.)

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?